# iosMath IBDesignable errors

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

I am using iosMath and am getting the following error under an `IB Designables` heading:

`Main2.storyboard: error: IB Designables: Failed to render and update auto layout status for VCFormulas (FJx-Ad-oa3): Failed to load designables from path (null)`

The viewController has nothing but some label outlets and statements such as the following:

```
let description = "Pythagorean Theorem"
let formula = "a^2+b^2=c^2"
labelDescription.text = description
labelFormula.latex = formula
```

It WILL build and run but I have to "Clean Build Folder" before it will build when switching between an iPhone 6 simulator and an iPad simulator. I sure would like to be rid of those errors!  (I also don't know if submission to the App Store will be a problem.)

**EDIT:**
When I click on a label of class 'MTMathUILabel', on the Identity Inspector, I get a Designable Error.  Clicking on that shows:
a[image]

Comment: When you open a storyboard, one of the options in the sidebar on the right will be to debug the IBDesignable of a view that failed to load. Use that to step through your code and find the problem.

Comment: Ok, I found the error message in the Identity Inspector, but can't find the debug option.  I added the error in my original post.

Comment: lol, no, I've been searching for several hours now with no luck.  I did find that I need to select a `MTMathUILabel` label (not the entire viewController) to activate "Debug Selected Views" in the Editor menu, but when I pressed "Refresh All Views" it has been 'Preparing to debug instance of "MTMathUILabel"' for about an hour.

Comment: I've also gotten into the Console and search for `IBDesignablesAgent` but it does not appear.

Comment: Aw man, bummer. I don't have any other ideas for this.

Comment: well, thank you for trying!